# Angular.js Call $http.get every second

Tags: angularjs, http, get, seconds, method-call

How can I call *$http.get* every second to update my page?

```
var app = angular.module("CompanionApp", []);

app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.LoginSubmit = function() {
        $http.get('/api/player/' + $scope.name)
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.connected = res.data.connected;
            $scope.health = res.data.health;
            $scope.armour = res.data.armour;
        })
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$interval` :

```
var app = angular.module("CompanionApp", []);

app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
    var interval;
    $scope.LoginSubmit = function() {
      interval = $interval(function () {
        $http.get('/api/player/' + $scope.name)
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.connected = res.data.connected;
            $scope.health = res.data.health;
            $scope.armour = res.data.armour;
        })
       }, 1000);
    };

    $scope.stopCalls = function(){ // incase you want to stop the calls using some button click
      $interval.cancel(interval);
    }
});
```